# The end of my end is my beginning

Tags: riddle

> My ends are twice,
>
> our ends are three,
>
> in the deep jungles below,
>
> green and blue vines listening above,
>
> And this is it,
>
> berry April, Berry Ten,
>
> Yes.
>
> Find the truth inbetween yellow and blue.
>
> Under the radar, under the sun.
>
> How tall am I, is the question - But you don't want to know.

What am I?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mindis the depth of an ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Ocean or the depth of an ocean perhaps.

My ends are twice.
Surface and depth of an ocean.

Our ends are three.
Death if we reach the depth of an ocean or get drown.

In the deep jungles below,
Green and blue vines listening above.
Phytoplankton or seaweed.

Berry April, berry ten.
April was the month the Titanic sinked.
'Berry' sounds like 'bury'.Like buried in the sea.
'Berry ten' i cannot understand.

Find the truth inbetween yellow and blue.
I think that means somewhere under the surface of the ocean but not deep enough so i can't see the sunlight.

Under the radar, under the sun.
Somewhere under the surface of the ocean.

How tall am I, is the question - But you don't want to know.
We don't want to  reach the depth of an ocean because we will die.